# QTableWidget: Only numbers via delegate

Tags: c++, qt, delegates, validation, qtablewidget

I'm currently trying to let my QTableWidget only display numbers. I read that I'd need a QAbstractItemDelegate to do so, so I read through the documentation and found the createEditor void. Here's my code I'm currently using:

```
#include "tabledelegate.h"

TableDelegate::TableDelegate(QObject *parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QWidget* TableDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent,const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QLineEdit* editor = new QLineEdit(parent);
    QDoubleValidator* val = new QDoubleValidator(editor);
    val->setBottom(0);
    val->setNotation(QDoubleValidator::StandardNotation);
    editor->setValidator(val);
    return editor;
}
```

And I'm trying to call the Delegate by doing this in the constructor of MainWindow:

```
ui->tableWidget->setItemDelegate(new TableDelegate(ui->tableWidget));
```

But it gives me this error:

> no matching function for call to 'QTableWidget::setItemDelegate(TableDelegate*)'
>        ui->tableWidget->setItemDelegate(new TableDelegate(ui->tableWidget));
>                                                                           ^

Why?

Comment: What if you call `ui->tableWidget->setItemDelegate(new TableDelegate());`? I don't think you need to set the table as a parent object of the delegate when you set the delegate to that very table.

Comment: No, this gives me a very similar error.

Comment: @vahancho: setting no parent is not a good idea. As the documentation says, QAbstractItemView does _not_ take ownership of the delegate, which means you'll have a memory leak if you don't set a parent.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an item delegate, you can achieve this behaviour by subclassing QTableWidgetItem and override the setData method:

```
void my_table_item::setData(int role, const QVariant& value)
{
    if(role == Qt::EditRole)
    {
        QObject* parent = 0; // reference call needed for linux
        QRegExpValidator rxv(QRegExp("[+-]?\\d*\\.?\\d+"), parent);
        int pos = 0;
        QString tmp = value.toString(); // reference call needed by linux
        if(rxv.validate(tmp,pos) != QValidator::Acceptable) { return; }
    }
    this->QTableWidgetItem::setData(role, value);
}
```

Note: The input is only validated when the user presses enter, not while he is inputting the data.

Comment: What is my_table_item supposed to be? I don't find a documentation for setData in QAbstractItemDelegate, so it has to be something different.

Comment: This is a different solution which does not use an item delegate at all but subclasses QTableWidgetItem. I edit my answer so it clearly states that.

Comment: Ah okay. But as I use the TableWidget from my UI, where to put this void? As I've got no own class for my QTableWidgetItems.

Comment: As stated, for this approach you have to subclass the QTableWidgetItem. I have no experience with itemDelegate to this is what I refer to usually. Subclassing QTableWidgetItem and overriding a single method is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I wrote the comment before your edit, so I did not saw it, that's clear, alright. I'll try to implement it and report back, thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself! A few mistakes I made:

- I forgot to subclass QStyledItemDelegate in my header file.
- I forgot to reimplement the other three needed functions setEditorData(),
  setModelData() and updateEditorGeometry().
- I had to run a QMake.

Here's my new source:

```
//HEADER
#ifndef TABLEDELEGATE_H
#define TABLEDELEGATE_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class TableDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    TableDelegate(QObject* parent = 0);
    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
};

#endif // TABLEDELEGATE_H
```

//CPP

```
#include "tabledelegate.h"
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QDoubleValidator>
TableDelegate::TableDelegate(QObject *parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QWidget* TableDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent,const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QLineEdit* editor = new QLineEdit(parent);
    QDoubleValidator* val = new QDoubleValidator(editor);
    val->setBottom(0);
    val->setNotation(QDoubleValidator::StandardNotation);
    editor->setValidator(val);
    return editor;
}

void TableDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    double value = index.model()->data(index,Qt::EditRole).toDouble();
    QLineEdit* line = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
    line->setText(QString().setNum(value));
}

void TableDelegate::setModelData(QWidget* editor,QAbstractItemModel* model,const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QLineEdit* line = static_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
    QString value = line->text();
    model->setData(index,value);
}

void TableDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}
```

Thanks to anyone who helped though.